# Why am I getting a 403 error response with my SurveyMonkey API get request?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, surveymonkey

I have attempted to follow the SurveyMonkey API documentation to a tee, just to get familiar with it before I move into the very simple functionality of my private application.

I have pretty much attempted to duplicate exactly what I've found in the documentation, but am getting a 403 response. You can see the exact snipped of code here in the docs: https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/docs?python#surveys-id

```
api_token = 'MyVerySecretApiKey'

survey_id = 'ASillyLittleNumber'


s.headers.update ({
    "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % api_token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
})

HOST = "https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys/%s" % (survey_id)

print s.get(HOST)
```

I've printed the GET just to see what exactly I'm getting, and I'm getting Response [403]. I can't figure out what I've done, especially with such a simple application. I've checked my api token and the survey id several time for accuracy. Is there anything I'm not understanding about the code from the documentation?

I've passed my api key and survey id as strings, and that's correct right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine - the `requests` module will take care of integers / strings in your headers, no need to worry about that.

The only thing I can think of is that maybe you're confusing your API key with your bearer token - based on this line:

```
api_token = 'MyVerySecretApiKey'
```

Check the settings page on your SM dev page and see if you can generate a bearer token for your account, and if it differes from the API key.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. You got me going back into the settings for my dev account and I saw that you have to let the app have certain scopes via the dev portal (though I would imagine you could permit them in app). I got a 200 response, which I think is good... Just need to figure out how to display/download the info! Thanks!